# Does REPLACE function in SQL Server accept input from a table for 'string_pattern' parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace

I'm still learning my ropes with SQL Server and maybe this question sounds very naive/ridiculous. Please bear with me on this. :)

I saw a function in SQL Server defined as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CleanNumeric]
    (
    @InputString VARCHAR(500)
    )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(500)
as
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, n.Symbol, '')
    FROM 
        NonNumeric n
    RETURN @InputString
END
```

`NonNumeric` is a table with a column named, `[Symbol]`, containing a bunch of non-numeric ASCII characters. From looking at SQL Server documentation for [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql), I don't think it (`REPLACE`) accepts a table's column nor does it seem to accept a cursor. Is it because we are using `REPLACE` in function context? If someone could point me to a good resource that explains it, I'd greatly appreciate that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is this function attempting to do? Is it stripping every character from a string that is non-numeric?

Comment: Perhaps a more robust example of what you are trying to accomplish.   There may be more efficient ways than a scalar function

Comment: @Prdp No, this will use all tables values dynamically and do the replacement step by step like the old-fashioned string concatenation with `SELECT @result=@result +  ',' + SomeColumn FROM SomeTable`...

Comment: @Shnugo - Yeah it works. http://rextester.com/live/XUWA81329  Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hacky trick called [Quirky Update](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/5150/please-can-somebody-explain-how-quirky-updates-wor.html)

This is slow and in most cases **something one should avoid**

Some examples:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SomeInt INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (1),(2),(3);

DECLARE @SumOfInts INT=0
SELECT @SumOfInts = @SumOfInts + SomeInt FROM @tbl;
SELECT @SumOfInts; --SELECT SUM(SomeInt) FROM @tbl is clearly better...)
```

String concatenation

```
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE(SomeText VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c');

DECLARE @ConcatString VARCHAR(100)='';
SELECT @ConcatString = @ConcatString + ', ' + SomeText FROM @tbl2;
SELECT @ConcatString;
```

Better was the usual approach with `FOR XML PATH('')` and `STUFF()`, which is a hacky workaround too. (Newer versions will bring a built-in function at last!)

### With `REPLACE` it works!

This *Quirky Update* is the only way I know to use a table's values for a *step-by-step* replacement of many values you can maintain in a table dynamically:

Look at this:

```
DECLARE @ReplaceValues TABLE(this VARCHAR(100),[by] VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @ReplaceValues VALUES('$',' Dollar'),('€',' Euro'),('abbr.','abbreviations');

DECLARE @SomeText VARCHAR(MAX)=
'This text is about 100 $ or 100 € and shows how to replace abbr.!';

SELECT @SomeText=REPLACE(@SomeText,this,[by]) FROM @ReplaceValues;

SELECT @SomeText;
```

The result

```
--This text is about 100  Dollar or 100  Euro and shows how to replace abbreviations!
```

Comment: Sql Server is so weird :D

Comment: @Prdp Yeah! If you introduce a forced order (Some `Rank` column) you can even do replacement cascades, where you replace a value within a part of the string which came there by a replacement too. We used this very successfully with heavy XML generation (CDA documents).

Comment: Certainly, in older versions of SQL, we were warned *against* computing aggregates in this manner (an example given was string concatenation) because the server would *not* guarantee to evaluate the `SELECT` clause exactly once per row. It may appear to work, but since  the warning still persists in the documentation (albeit referencing a KB article for very old product versions), I'd prefer to avoid it.

Comment: See the last paragraph in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql#remarks): "Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur. This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once for each output row"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well, I know this, and I would not advise to use *quirky updates* (I wrote *something one should avoid*), but admittably with replacement values taken from a table I do use it (and I did not encounter any problems so far). AFAIK there is no other *ad-hoc* approach to achieve the same...

Comment: If you use the quirky update there are a number of extremely critical elements that MUST be followed or it will not work. See Jeff Moden's article on the topic here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/ Make sure you scroll down to the bottom where he clearly defines a number of rules for this to work.

Comment: @SeanLange, I did read this article before, I even (indirectly) linked it myself, as it is in the accepted answer, when you follow the link behind *Quirky Update*... One must be aware, that the article was written for SQL-Server 2000. And Jeff Moden himself commented (in 2010) his own article (see the link I provided).

Comment: @Shnugo Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I learned a quirky feature in SQL Server today. :)

Comment: @Shnugo my comment was meant for the OP, I sort of assumed you knew those details. :)

Comment: @Shnugo Thank you for the reminder. I was waiting on accepting an answer partly because 1) questions like mine don't really have a definitive answer and 2) I'd like to wait and see who would provide the most comprehensive and clear answer for the question. But I agree with you. People on SO answer volunteer their time by answering questions from random strangers, so we should always try to acknowledge their help in any way possible. Cheers and thank you again!

Comment: @user1330974 Sorry for pushing... A short look into your profile shows clearly, that you did accept in most cases... Should have waited... Well, if there comes a better / more comprehensive answer feel free to shift your acceptance to which ever answer you consider best. Happy Coding!

Comment: @Shnugo Thank you for your understanding and sharing knowledge on SO! Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes you can use the value from a column for any place in SQL Server's syntax where a value is expected (as opposed to where a *name* is expected, such as the first argument to `DATEPART`).

However, this is broken code - it appears to *assume* that each row will be evaluated in sequence and each row will be evaluated using values produced from previous rows. However, SQL Server only guarantees to [perform one assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#remarks) (for the "last" row - however, with no `ORDER BY` clause, "last" is ill-defined):

> If the SELECT statement returns more than one value, the variable is assigned the last value that is returned.

Whether it may appear to work is no *guarantee* that more than a single assignment will actually take place.

Answer (score 2):

Replace accepts the table column, and in this case it will do exactly what you expect it to do. It will do iterations on @InputString variable and exclude all non numeric characters that appear in the NonNumeric table and in the @InputString variable.

Comment: That is so wrong!!. In each row one symbol will replaced. By no means all the symbols in `@InputString` will be replaced. Finally a random record will be returned, which will have only one symbol replaced.

Comment: @Prdp While I am not advocating the approach, I don't think this answer is completely wrong. I think you may have misunderstood the function. It is not replacing the values in the column, rather using values from the column to update a variable. This does work - http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=94975ddb4827dff187e1a249937d27f1 - However, I don't think it is guaranteed to work, and could be like variable concatenation which relies on the internal pathways SQL Server takes, so the results could still be unexpected.

Comment: @GarethD - Thats ridiculous. It works http://rextester.com/live/XUWA81329. It is working like quiry update method

Comment: @Prdp Take a look at the answer I just provided. There's a working example that this will really do a *step-by-step* replacement...

Comment: I stand corrected my initial comment was wrong. Between I did not downvote so can't remove it. To nullify will upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it will work with the table column and do a replace for each row in your table. But it only work because the `@InputString` variable is affected each time.

Maybe you could use a [local temporary table](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/tables/local_temp.php) to store your NonNumeric

Be carefull because you are returning a NVARCHAR value while `@InputString` is a VARCHAR.

Answer (score 1):

A simple code to show you that the `REPLACE` can accept values from a `table`

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Test VARCHAR(20)
)

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES ('James')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES ('John')

GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CleanNumeric]
    (
    @InputString VARCHAR(500),
    @Test VARCHAR(500)
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN(
 SELECT
        REPLACE(@InputString, n.Test, '') AS Test
    FROM 
        dbo.Test n WHERE Test = @Test)
GO

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fn_CleanNumeric] ('TestJohn','John')
```

### Result

```
Test
--------
TestT
```

The `SELECT` takes a random value and will check for that `string pattern` in the variable `@InputString`, thus passing a @Test variable ensures to `REPLACE` the right string pattern