# How to replace a list of words?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am on SQL-Server 2012 (maybe 2016). My Problem:

I have a list of words within a table

```
create table #wordlist (searchword varchar(255) not null)

insert #wordlist (searchword) values ('Private_1'), ('Private_2'), ('Private_3')
```

and a table with a text column, containing this words and other information within the text:

```
create table #texts (mytext varchar(2000) not null)

insert #texts (mytext) values ('This text was written by Private_1.'), ('Private_3: My memo'), ('My name is Private_2. I feel free! (Private_1, Private_2)')
```

I would like to replace the 'searchword' from 'mytext' with 'xxx'

The desired result is

```
'This text was written by xxx'
'xxx: My memo'
'My name is xxx. I feel free! (xxx, xxx)'
```

I am looking for a solution that can handle massdata. A cursor over the #wordlist replacing the data one-by-one like

```
replace (mytext, @searchword, 'xxx')
```

is no option. My #wordlist contains some 100000 words, my #texts contain about 3000 million rows. A full table scan takes about 15 minutes (about 1 TB to read).

The cursor would need 7 years... Maybe an index would speed up by the factor of 1000, what would make it running 2 days.

Is there a way to replace a list of words with 'xxx'?

(A simple aproach like shown in [Does REPLACE function in SQL Server accept input from a table for 'string_pattern' parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632965/does-replace-function-in-sql-server-accept-input-from-a-table-for-string-patter) will not work - see calculation above.)

Comment: An index is unlikely to help any, nor is the extra logic you would presumably need to deal with false sub-string matches, perhaps an rdbms is not the right tool for this.

Comment: How do you plan to handle word delimiters? For example, if you were going to remove words like "cat", "tad" and "catadioptrism" you need to use either a specific order for replacements or parse out word boundaries, e.g. if you replace "cat" or "tad" in "catadioptrism" then you won't replace the larger word.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be long and cumbersome. SQL is not the best choice of tool for this. It *is* possible to express this as a recursive CTE that processes one word at a time. However, with 3 billion rows in the outer table and 100,000 words to process that will take . . . well, roughly forever.

Hopefully, you can freeze the tables you are working on for a few days. I would recommend writing code in something like Python and doing:

- Read in the word list into an array
- Read a bunch of records, say 100,000 at a time.
- Loop through the words for each record and do the replacement.
- Repeat and repeat.

You can parallelize this operation by running multiple copies of the script and running them on different records.

This is a big effort. If someone expects you to be done in a day or two, the expectations are way off.

Comment: The linked answer shows an approach using *quirky update*...

Comment: @Shnugo . . . It doesn't really change the fact that the database will basically never return.

Comment: You are right, the pure mass of data is the issue - more than the approach / tool. Plused your answer, as it provides some useful hints.